# Multiplying a register value by a constant in MIPS?

Tags: mips, multiplication

I'm learning how to do MIPS and i'm confused on multiplication. Let's say I was converting the following C Code into MIPS.

```
c = b + a*3
```

with a,b,c stored in registers $s1,$s2,$s3 respectively. How am I supposed to write a*3 in MIPS? Is there an addi type instruction for multiplication or do I store 3 in a temporary register and use the mult operator like this?

```
addi $t0, $zero, 3
mult $s1,$t0
```

If so how do I get the final value or product of this operation to complete my C code?

Comment: The 64-bit product is in the `lo` and `hi` registers. Use the `mflo` and `mfhi` instructions to get their values (or just `mflo` if you're only interested in the 32 least significant bits). Consult a MIPS instruction set reference for more info on those instructions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MIPS instruction set doesn't provide a mult instruction with immediate value. Hence you would have to store the value into a temporary register and then use mult instructions. The result of the mult instruction would be stored in lo and hi registers giving the lower 32-bit of the result and upper 32-bit of the result respectively.

Comment: so in this case, if a is something small like a = 3 then I would only be interested in " mflo " correct?

Comment: @maxbr7t Yes, that's right. If you know that `$hi` will contain zero ahead of time, feel free to ignore it.